# Is there a TI-82 emulator?

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, texas-instruments

I have a blue TI-82 that doesn't have a computer input, and there for I have to code every program by hand. 
And on all tests I have to clear the memory so I don't have any programs installed (I could cheat if I didn't).

I really would like to play Blockdude, I haven't played that game in 3 years.

So my question is, is there a emulator of the TI-8x that lets me play Blockdude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [wxWabbitemu](http://code.google.com/p/wxwabbitemu/)

A linux based TI emulator exists that uses the wxWidgets code libraries.

Compile instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
svn checkout http://wxwabbitemu.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ wxwabbitemu-read-only
cd wxwabbitemu-read-only/src
sudo apt-get install wx2.8-headers wx-common libwxgtk2.8-dev
chmod +x ./build_wx
./build_wx
```

To run it, type, in the same directory:

```
./wxwabbitemu
```

You'll need a licensed ROM for this to work - google that one.

Legally - Texas Instruments themselves distribute the TI83 variant with their SDK

```
wget http://education.ti.com/calculators/downloads/US/Software/Download/en/177/6560/83psdk_setup.exe
```

TI83Plus.clc for the TI-83+, TI83ps.clc for the TI-83+ Silver Edition and TI73.clc for the TI-73
N.B. copy and rename as .rom for the application to work correctly.

Links:

1. See [this forum entry](http://www.unitedti.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=9220) as to the advantages/disadvantages of using these ROMs.
2. See [this wiki](http://wikiti.brandonw.net/index.php?title=Emulators:Wabbitemu) for operating instructions - e.g. F12 to turn on

[image]

### [Blockdude](http://oos.moxiecode.com/examples/blockdude/index.html)

... or there is a Flash based remake

[image]

Comment: that remake is truly AWESOME :)
But I would alos like a emulator since I have a TI-82.

Comment: wow, it's compiling in color! :)

Answer (score 2):

Tilem is available on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tilem/).

> **Tilem - TI Linux Emulator** An emulator for the Z80 series of Texas Instruments graphing calculators. It emulates all current Z80 calculator models except the TI-81, and features a debugger, external file loading, and full flash support, including flash app loading.

[image]

You need to [compile the source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1687776)... so fossfreedom's answer might be easier ;)

Comment: I compiled that source and I got a whole lot of warnings. Sorry even the slow Flash version is better...